# Кэширование JSON

Tags: java, mysql, оптимизация

Есть сложный бизнес запрос в БД. **Время выполнения составляет примерно 20 минут**. Он дальше передается в виде JSON.

*Актуальность информации в реальном времени не нужна* (достаточно поддерживать актуальность за сутки).

##### Как ускорить ответ?

***Вижу варианты:***

1. По таймеру раз в сутки ночью формировать JSON, хранить на сервере, при обращении отдавать (Вопрос в реализации, как передать готовый json)?
2. Кэшировать данные со стороны sql (БД MySQL 5, возможно нельзя будет включить или будет не оптимально работать)
3. Создавать с некоторой периодичностью временную таблицу и брать из неё все нужные колонки
4. Может быть какие-то более элегантные решения?

Для понимания, это легаси проект на java 7, никаких спрингов, хиберов и прочего добра, старый добрый jdbc и много-много плохо написанного кода который легко сломать.

Comment: Комбинация 1 + 3. Только таблица - статическая.